# Does falsificationism claim that all reasoning should be scientific?

Tags: scientific-method, reason, popper, falsifiability

Does falsificationism claim that all reasoning should be scientific? I don't think much of philosophy is falsifiable. Does that mean we should abandon it? Should we believe that 'love' doesn't exist, because there's no empirical test to prove it doesn't (same as there being black swans)?

etc.

Comment: No, it is the other way around. It claims that falsifiability is a necessary feature of mature scientific hypotheses, it is not meant to apply outside of science, e.g. to ethics or aesthetics. Even within science, Popper admitted so-called "metaphysical research programs" that can explore unfalsifiable assumptions, albeit with the goal of formulating falsifiable hypotheses eventually.

Comment: thanks! i agree @Conifold

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A proposition is non-falsifiable. So what?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22763/a-proposition-is-non-falsifiable-so-what)